# Adding spinner in new NavigationView in android design support library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

With new NavigationView in android we can create drawers like one bellow (src: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

Now each list item in the drawer can be defined in form of menu:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
    android:checked="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
    android:title="@string/navigation_item_1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
    android:title="@string/navigation_item_2"/>
</group>
```

My navigation drawer contains a header and list of items, 1 of these items is a spinner selector where as rest are single click items.

So, what is the best way in which I can have a spinner inside the items list?